# What is the purpose of encrypting data at rest with AWS KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

I'm currently going about setting up encryption on AWS DynamoDB for individual columns on a table that are deemed sensitive. From my research, I've decided that the best way of doing this is likely with AWS KMS. From this sprouted a (perhaps very basic) question about the fundamental workings of doing this.

The true purpose, I would suppose, of me encrypting this data is to prevent people from accessing my data via a compromised AWS account (and perhaps AWS itself being compromised, but I'd imagine that's secondary). However, if my AWS account is compromised... doesn't the attacker have access to my KMS key (not directly, but the ability to use the API to encrypt and decrypt data?)

This is a really basic question, I'm sure, but I feel like I can't move forward with a hole in my knowledge this big.

Comment: You do have 2-factor authentication enabled, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of having KMS is to protect your data while the key is never visible to your application since the key never leaves KMS. You submit data to AWS KMS to be encrypted, or decrypted, under keys that you control. You set usage policies on these keys that determine which users can use them to encrypt and decrypt data. All requests to use these keys are logged in AWS CloudTrail so you can understand who used which key when.

Having KMS makes it impossible for an attacker to get the encryption keys. Even if an attacker get on hold of your AWS Account(Assuming he gets Admin Access and KMS Access) and use KMS to decrypt a message, you will be able to see that through the logs in accessing these keys which is a necessary security steps to identify these threats.

So in general, if you provide least privilege to users(Not allowing everyone to access KMS), while keeping root account safe with MFA, it will be really difficult for an attacker to access KMS.

Comment: I guess what I'm worried about is the following: I can lock down permissions on my EC2 instance for KMS, which is where I'll need do the encrypting/decrypting of data. That's protected by my private key - nobody can get in to that without it. But what about our ElasticBeanstalk setup, which is used to deploy? Seems like a big hole - anyone who had permission to ELB could deploy a version, with their own custom code, to EC2 that decrypted and copied our data to some outside source. Thoughts on this?

Comment: Yes its true if a person has access to Elastic Beanstalk attacker can do what he wants. But still what KMS does is reducing the attack surface.

Comment: Fair enough :) it certainly does that - i wonder if i can look in to locking down ELB somehow as well. Thanks much for your help my friend!